# Is this a good practice for AJAX-website, and should I make PHP work inside .html-files, or change to .php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Issue: I want to run PHP from inside HTML docs, to include HTML via PHP include();.

Q:

Would it be better to change .php to .txt, for my AJAX-loaded pages, and change my .html files to .php?

This would perhaps solve it, but it would be much easier if it worked to allow PHP in HTML. But is that a bad practice, to allow PHP in HTML?

I have my setup described below, to understand my problem with choosing file-extension for my pages/allowing PHP in HTML.

I have an Ajax app, with pure JavaScript.
The AJAX-content files, are with .php extension, and in htaccess I strip away .php from any URL in my site.

Then, in my pushstate, I use the 'data-name + (.html)', in my third statement/parameter for pushstate.

This way the URL will show .html, even if the actual loaded content is from my .php file.

This then solves my refresh and deep-links, as it will always be .html in the URL bar, and the .html file exist's when a user goes directly to that URL.

To run PHP in HTML:

It seems I need access to httpd.conf, which I am looking into, and have asked my server-people if this is supported, and if they can activate it.

Is this kind of setup for a webpage 'generally accepted'?
Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong in terms of 'generally accepted'?
Maybe not fit for Q/A, but common practice's should be OK to ask about.

Comment: if you use html, php operations has to be done only in ajax. other case you may do the php side in page postbacks. But if you are Single page Application  you may think of html.

Comment: For heaven's sake, if you need to run php in a file (even if it's a `<?php include(); ?>`), use `.php` ; BTW it seem you make a big mess with AJAX/ PHP and server-side/client-side....

Comment: I see, yes I understood the difference, but haven't gone alot into dept about what belongs where..
and am asking before jumping into changing, but I will change it to .php, it seems more logic, so yeah, for heaven's sake like you put it, is probably in place..

Comment: thanks for pointing out <AJAX/ PHP and server-side/client-side>, I had not given that thought at all!
That may be the most difficult part about google-schooling, putting all the pieces together properly, when much of the basics are probably missing.
But I am getting there, ok I do the changes etc, is it any point then to use include for my html pages, or is it more logic to have normal html pages, as backup tp my ajaxApp? I understand ajax is for 'load' performance boosting, and what it does behind there.

Comment: @sunto take a look at my post, I add some info on this part ;)

Comment: @sunto even for template (pure Html) it's really common to use `.php` as it harmonize the whole project

Comment: yeah, it is for use of a template! 
Actually that would be the only php I am doing, so why I actually have .php as extension is probably just silly..
Mistaken with server-language, and ajax/js doing talking to the server-stuff I guess. Thanks for directing my onto the path of righteousness again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need some php somewhere in your website, the common use is to move everything to `.php` extension (even file that use html with JS only).

If someone other than you need to put his hands in this app, changing the default worldwide assuming behaviour of the server is **definitely not a good practice**.

And if you think changing extension to `.html` allow you to avoid hacking / making magic trick, then you should learn how to really secure your app or use .htaccess rewriting to change the look of your URL.

---

For your knowledge :

- PHP is a server side proceeded language, running on `.php` file
- html is a structural language used by the client browser to apply css
- css is the design rules language used by the client browser to stylize the html
- JavaScript is a client side proceeded language, running in html usually
- AJAX is (±) the use of JavaScript to hit the server and bring back some content if needed

By default on web server, a browser that get back php generate content expect it to be in `text/HTML` language (you can change it by the use of `header()`)

**For AJAX**, you can totally avoid using it in fact, the only true down side is that you'll have to reload the page (and wait the server to process the required action) every time you need to hit the server. AJAX allow you to make these call as background task in the client browser, like

> "save this form and tell me when you're done"

or

> "my user change the filter used, could you send me the products for `tag=newTag`".

Comment: Really apprecated, You pointed out many things I had not even considered, like security!
I was probably mistaken as to how to use php, thou somewhere in there I knew what it is, and the things you point out is probably pretty obvious, if I had only given it thought like that!

So thanks alot for pointing out that, and for answering not only that I shouldn't, but also why I shouldn't do changes to the httpd.conf file on the server, and just have the correct extensions for my files!

Comment: @sunto I've added a small part for AJAX ; and you're welcome, glad to help, keep going even if it's a bit hard at the begging, you can found good tutorial on the web ;)

Comment: I saw that, nice. 
I came by the include, and after adding a hard copy of html, refresh works, and ajax still works etc, it is just a one page app, so as much is probably presumable.
And thats why I want to use include, my 'html' pages(I will change that to be php, And url to be .php as this will find the correct file for a new user or onpageload), will then only contain some lines of php code, and also include my, oh crap.. no longer .php files.(My structure now is, file.php + file.html). I think file.php=file.txt and file.html=file.php is ok, but then the include cant include the text.

Comment: Continues:
I want: save html stuff in templates.
include them in .php files(functioning as a fallback for ajax).
Then I have some choices I guess.
I could include html, and have the textcontent of file, be both in file.txt(for ajax) and in file.php(for fallback). I can't have both, as I cant have 2 copies of file.php(I need a direct url for my static fallback page working also). So I guess, I will go for include the html stuff, and just add the textcontent twice, at least it saves work on the most important, my menu :) This a logical sollution you think?

Comment: Sorry, I could probably 'include("file.txt")' inside my php file right?

Comment: you don't need `.txt` I think... (but I've got some problem to understand how you deal with your files) ; more or less : put everything in `.php`

Comment: Hehe yeah ok. 
When I am running ajax, I dont want my "includes", to be in the document fetched by ajax. 
But I could just adjust my ajax I guess, and only get the content of a div, but then again, why bother with ajax for this app is probably the more correct question.
I will try and keep the ajax working, but at the same time have a good structure, like you say with only one page! That is naturally what I want, as is why I didn't even have the backup html solution, and therefore no refresh-solution, until two days ago.
Therefore I am adjusting the page to work, and want the best option.

Comment: @sunto if you just start coding, I think keeping away AJAX may be a good idea, it'll not bring you anything than pain... try to make you app without, and after you can add some to don't refresh

Comment: I started 1 year ago with js, and ajax was a good way to learn event handling, and I realize it can be used better in other ways also, but thanks for the tip:)